# Pseudo inverse of matrix with special form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Consider $A=BC$. A has orthonormal columns. I want to verify that the inverse $D=C^+ B^+ $ satisfies Penrose properties.

The following holds: $ CDC = ABB^+A^*AB = ABB^+B \overset{!}{=} AB = C $

Why can I state that $B^+ B= I$?

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse

Comment: $B^+B = I$ holds if and only if $B$ has linearly independent columns, which need not be the case here.

Comment: How can I verify this result then?

Comment: Can you state more clearly what result you're trying to prove exactly? It's not clear why you're looking at $CDC$ in the first place

Comment: It is one of the penrose axioms. I have to proof CDC =C

Comment: Maybe I can use that B+ is pseudo inverse of B?

Comment: the Penrose axiom would be $ADA = A$, not $CDC = C$

Comment: Sorry I messed up the order. It should $ C=AB$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that if $C = AB$, $A$ has orthonormal columns, and $D = C^+B^+$, then we have $CDC = C$ (as would be required in order to have $D = C^+$).

As you have correctly shown, we have
$$
CDC = ABB^+A^*AB = ABB^+B.
$$
Although it does not necessarily hold that $BB^+ = I$, it does hold that $BB^+B = B$ (since this is one of the axioms). So, we indeed have
$$
CDC = A(BB^+B) = AB = C,
$$
as was desired.

Comment: Thank you very much:)